# Can I manually install my TestFlight built IPA somehow?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

Say I go into Xcode's Organizer and Export my app as an IPA with the "App Store" setting so I can submit it to TestFlight.

Can I install the resulting IPA on my device manually somehow?

Comment: Apple Configurator? That's what I use to install the IPA from an Ad Hoc export. Or maybe you could just _do_ an Ad Hoc export; it's the same binary (the archive), so it will work just the same way.

Comment: Ok thanks Matt I'll just do that didnt know!

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode go to Devices (Window -> Devices & Simulator). Use `+` under Installed Apps to upload it manually.

Comment: you can also drag and drop the app to the simulator from the products folder in xcode